# Numric Regex with ":" how to add

Tags: regex

Im using the following Regex which is working fine for numbers only
currently I need to add ":" how should I do that?

this is not working for me...

```
@"^[0-9](:)+\s*$"
```

for example accept values like

```
80:80
8000
8
```

Comment: Your regexp matches one digit followed by at least one `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following regex:

`^\d[\d:]*\s*$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dK7mU3

Answer (score 0):

```
 @"^[0-9][\d:]*\s*$"
```

will do it for you as it adds the colon along with digits

your regex makes the presence of `:` mandatory. thus it wont match all your examples.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/bQ2xI7

Comment: simply change the regex and see the matches in blue